# C++'s default inheritance access specifier?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have some legacy code that I have to wrap, and I have come across this declaration:

```
class Foo : Bar
{
    // ...
};
```

This seems to compile under GCC.  I know it's bad, but I can't change it.  My question is, if no inheritance access specifier is present, how does the C++ compiler handle it?

Comment: Actually, I would say that it is *not* bad. I would call redundantly specifying the access specifier bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

BTW, it is not called access modifier. It is called access specifier

> $11.2/2 - "In the absence of an
>   access-specifier for a base class,
>   public is assumed when the derived
>   class is defined with the class-key
>   struct and private is assumed when the
>   class is defined with the class-key
>   class."

In your context, 'Bar' is a private base class of 'Foo'

Answer (score 10):

For classes, the default is `private`.

For structs, the default is `public`.

Answer (score 1):

It's `private`.