# Default inheritance access specifier

Tags: c++, inheritance

If I have for example two classes `A` and `B`, such that class `B` inherits `A` as follows:

`class B: public A`

In this case, I'm doing `public` inheritance.

If I write the previous code as follows:

`class B: A`

What type of inheritance will I be doing here (i.e; public)? In other words, what is the default access specifier?

Just a side question here. Do I call the previous line of codes `statements`? Especially that I remember I read in the *C++ Without Fear: A Beginner's Guide That Makes You Feel Smart* book that `statements` are that that end with `;`. What do you think about that?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784983/do-i-kill-a-kitten-each-time-i-use-struct-everywhere-instead-of-class/

Comment: Statements appear only within function definitions.

Comment: Aschepler's statement is incorrect.

Comment: @Noah: counter-example please

Comment: -1: This is trivially answerable with Google: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%2B%2B+default+inheritance+specifier.

Comment: @Noah: sorry, but as I see all the *statements* are children of *function-body* according to the grammar.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: Why is @aschepler statement wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++'s default inheritance access specifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964982/cs-default-inheritance-access-specifier)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It's not actually that bad to have an **high quality** FAQ asked and answered in SO, since anyone can save time by redirecting beginners here with easily updated info and good format. BTW, that Google link now shows this page as the first result.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Just a small addition to all the existing answers: the default type of the inheritance depends on the inheriting (derived) type (`B` in the example), not on the one that is being inherited (base) (`A` in the example).

For example:

```
class A {};
struct B: /* public */ A {};
```

```
struct A {};
class B: /* private */ A {};
```

Comment: I believe (at least it's what Clang does) the term is "tag" (to refer to the item which is one of class/struct/union) -- That is to say, the default inheritance type is determined by the tag type (tag kind?) of the inheriting type.

Answer (score 31):

It's private for class and public for struct.

Side answer: No, these are *definitions* of the class according to the standard. Class definition end with a semicolon. On the other hand not all statements end with a semicolon (e.g. an `if` statement does not).

Answer (score 7):

When you inherit a class from another class (inherit `class Base` from `class Derived` in this case), then the default access specifier is `private`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Base {
public:
int x;
};

class Derived : Base { }; // is equilalent to class Derived : private Base       {}

int main()
{
 Derived d;
 d.x = 20; // compiler error becuase inheritance is private
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

When you inherit a class from a structure (inherit `class Base` from `struct Derived` in this case), then the default access specifier is `public`.

```
#include < stdio.h >
  class Base {
    public:
      int x;
  };

struct Derived: Base {}; // is equilalent to struct Derived : public Base {}

int main() {
  Derived d;
  d.x = 20; // works fine becuase inheritance is public
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use `class` to define your class, the default access specifier will be `private`. (I think it's wrong, too.) If you use `struct`, however, it will be `public`.

And class definitions are declarations, I think. A statement is what translates into actual code (unless optimized away, anyway).
However, a mildly exotic feature of C and C++ is that expressions are statements. That's why `3+4;` is a syntactically legal statement in C++ (although many compilers will warn about it having no effect). While it is obviously nonsense in this case, in general expressions are evaluated for their side effects. (An obvious example is discarding a function's return value. You call the function not to obtain a result, but for its side effects.)

Comment: "A statement is what translates into actual code" No. In C++, a typedef is a statement, and does not itself correspond to any generated code.

What C++ considers to be a statement, differs from what C considers to be a statement. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49862170/


"expressions are statements" No. The semicolon operator has the effect of creating a statement from an expression, and discarding the expression's result. https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2472079&seqNum=4


"in general expressions are evaluated for their side effects" No. Arithmetic, for instance.

Comment: What do you think is wrong about default access specifier for classes being `private`?

Comment: @amn: When I write a class, I put the public part atop, not the private part, because the public part is what everybody should be interested in. So I can (almost) never use the default access specifier.

Answer (score 2):

The "type" of inheritance depends on how the class is defined. There are default access specifiers applied to inheritance. From the C++ standard:

[[class.access.base]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.access.base#2)

> In the absence of an access-specifier for a base class, public is
>   assumed when the derived class is defined with the class-key `struct`
>   and private is assumed when the class is defined with the class-key
>   `class`. [ Example:
>
> ```
> class B { /* ... */ };
> class D1 : private B { /* ... */ };
> class D2 : public B { /* ... */ };
> class D3 : B { /* ... */ };             // B private by default
> struct D4 : public B { /* ... */ };
> struct D5 : private B { /* ... */ };
> struct D6 : B { /* ... */ };            // B public by default
> class D7 : protected B { /* ... */ };
> struct D8 : protected B { /* ... */ };
> ```
>
> Here B is a public base of D2, D4, and D6, a private base of D1, D3,
>   and D5, and a protected base of D7 and D8.  — end example ]

Answer (score 1):

If you do not choose an inheritance, C++ defaults to `private` inheritance in the same way class members default to `private` access for classes.

Answer (score 1):

The default type of the inheritance is **private** in C++.

```
class B:A
{};
```

is equivalent to

```
class B: private A
{};
```

Comment: Since the question asks for default inheritance access specifier and has not limited the domain of the question to `class`, the general answer would be to consider inheritance for `struct` as well. If the child type is a `struct`, the default type of inheritance is public.

Answer (score 0):

the default access specifier is an important differentiator between classes and structs. It is public by default for structs and private by default for classes.

Answer (score 0):

AS other casting problem you have

```
class A { virtual void test() = 0; };
class B : virtual public A { virtual void testb() {} };
class C : virtual public A { virtual void testc() {} };
class D : public B, public C {
 virtual void test() override {}
}

void main() {
   D d;
   void* v = &d;
   A* a = &d;

   ((D*)A)->test(); //OK
   ((D*)v)->test(); //undefined behavior (that call testb() in vtable logic at 1st inheritance position)
   dynamic_cast<D*>(v)->test(); //compile error cast from void* not permitted

   //resolution
   void* x = a;
   ((D*)x)->test(); //OK but as you can see, you must to store a* in x*

}
```