# C++ inheritance type

Tags: c++, inheritance, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default inheritance access specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796789/default-inheritance-access-specifier)

When class `A` inherits from class `B`:

```
class A: B {...}
```

Since I didn't specify the type of inheritance, What will the type of inheritance be? Will it be `private` since it is the default? Or, is there some sort of dependency here? In other words, will the inheritance type depend on the `inherited` class or the `inheriting` class?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796789/default-inheritance-access-specifier The accepted answer has a nice explanation of the struct/class and class/struct inheritance cases.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify anything, it will be `private` by default for classes. For structs it will be `public` by default.