# What is the default mode (public, protected, or private) of inheritance in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

When I write

```
class Derived : Base { };
```

This compiles. (I sort of assumed that one needs to specify it as being one of `public`, `protected`, or `private` inheritance, which has consequences about the visibility of members.

Which one of the three is it if I do not specify?

Comment: Please explain downvote so I can improve the question.

Comment: It seems like this should be explained in any C++ textbook or tutorial.

Comment: I get answers when Googling the title.

Comment: Nope, I have found a large number of them and all explicitly write out which type

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4796789/1702990 Literally the first result when you google "c++ default inheritance access"

Comment: Cool. incidentally I did find an "answer" in [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/115-inheritance-and-access-specifiers/) article, which turns out to be wrong. it depends on what type of inheritance Base uses

Comment: @StevenLu that article says "If you do not choose an inheritance type, C++ defaults to private inheritance" . (which is correct). The line which says "the access specifiers may change depending on the method of inheritance" is talking about the access specifiers of the base class's members when they are inherited as part of a derived class.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Much obliged for your correction. This is what I get for trying to rush things...

Answer (score 2):

The default is "private" for classes, and "public" for structs.  This is also true for the default access mode of members in said classes and structs.

Answer (score 1):

> In a class, members are by default private; in a struct, members are by default public (§16.2.4).