# C++ - Deriving public functions from a parent class to use in main.cpp file

Tags: c++, c++17

The ERROR I'm having is in the main.cpp file. It's telling me to make .getName() a public function; I believe it is. How can I get around this issue?

My code is organized with two header files "abstractsales" and "salesperson". Salesperson inherits all characteristics of abstractsales including the "getName()" function. But again, cannot call this function in the main. Advise to my code below.

## Abstract sales:

```
class abstractsales{
private:
    // This class has no private variable as it's used for a parent for public functions
public:
    string name, position;
    int EID, bossID;

    /*
     * This abstract sales class generalizes the needs for each type of sales person
     * for them to adopt in subclasses.
     */
   // ===== Get Functions =====
    string getName(){
        return this->name;
    }
```

## SalesPerson Class:

```
class salesperson : abstractsales{
private:
    double commission = 0.05;
    double totalSalesProfit;
public:
    // Default Constructor
    salesperson(){
        this->name = "";
        this->position = "";
        this->EID = 0;
        this->bossID = 0;
        this->commission = 0.05;
    }
    // Constructor with appropriate parameters
    salesperson(string n, string p, int employeeID, int BID){
        this->name = p;
        this->position = n;
        this->EID = employeeID;
        this->bossID = BID;
        this->commission = 0.05;
    }

    // ===== Get Functions =====
    double getCommission(){
        return this->commission;
    }
    double getTotalProfit(){
        return totalSalesProfit;
    }

    // Function to add sale to total amount
    void addSale(double amt){
        totalSalesProfit += amt * commission;
    }
};
```

## ERROR presented in main.cpp:

// Attached Image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJqyr.png)

I've tried initializing the get function in salesperson class; however, abstractsales is used for multiple child classes. I'm unsure how to resolve this error.

Comment: Your inheritance is incorrect -- you are making everything from `abstractsales` private in how you are inheriting. You want `class salesperson : public abstractsales`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796789/default-inheritance-access-specifier

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between public, private, and protected inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected-inheritance)

Comment: First of all, please make sure to show us a [mre]. With emphasis on the *minimal* part. Secondly, [don't show images of errors (or any other text)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste the actual build-log into your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c++ you can have *public* inheritance, or *private* inheritance.  Public inheritance looks like this:

```
class Derived : public Base {...};
```

Private inheritance looks like this:

```
class Derived : private Base {...};
```

or

```
class Derived : Base {...};
```

In other words, inheritance is private by default, even though this is not what you want most of the time.

With public inheritance, all public members of `Base` become public members of `Derived`, and are visible to its users.  In other words, your derived class inherits both the implementation and the interface of the base class.

With private inheritance, public members of `Base` become private members of `Derived`.  So your derived class inherits only the implementation, but not the interface of the base class.

In vast majority of cases you want to use public inheritance.

Comment: It works now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have public inherit the base class.

```
class Foo: public Bar { ... }
```